# My function closest_power(base, num) failing some test cases

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def closest_power(base, num):
    '''
    base: base of the exponential, integer > 1
    num: number you want to be closest to, integer > 0
    Find the integer exponent such that base**exponent is closest to num.
    Note that the base**exponent may be either greater or smaller than num.
    In case of a tie, return the smaller value.
    Returns the exponent.

    '''

    result=0
    exp=1
    while base**exp<num:
        if base**exp <= num < base**(exp+1):
           result = exp

        elif num - base**exp <= base**(exp+1) - num:
           result=exp+1

        exp+=1
    return result
```

In my code, when I try running `closest_power(4,62)` it returns `2` instead of `3` and, in similar test cases like `closest_power(4, 12)` returns `1` instead of `2`. (`closest_power(5, 22)` returns `1` instead of `2`)

For rest of the test cases it works fine for example:

```
closest_power(2, 384.0)
```

returns `8`.

Why am I missing out those cases?

Comment: you'll need an else block on that if, elif chain.  Anyway, I recommend you to use a `log` to start, then you don't need to use a loop at all you can just pick from two values.

Comment: I don't want to use log . I want to know what case my code's loop is missing here for those specific test cases.

Comment: It's not hard to figure out, just run through the code in your head. Take the first case, `4,62` - the first pass `exp=1` doesn't hit either case, the second `exp=2` hits the first case and thus skips the second.

Comment: The loop is weird and over-complicated anyway, it should just be `while base**exp < num: exp += 1` then pick one of the two possibilities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first condition is always true until while condition violated. For example if `exp=1` => `4**1 <= 64 < 4**(1+1)` yields to true. If `exp=2` => `4**2 <= 64 < 4**(2+1)` also yields to true.

And when condition violated result is always equals to smaller exponent (result=exp). So calling `closest_power(4,62)` is same as calling `closest_power(4,18)` and returns `2`.

As @wim said your method is too complicated. Something like below would be more clear:

```
def closest_power(base, num):
    '''
    base: base of the exponential, integer > 1
    num: number you want to be closest to, integer > 0
    Find the integer exponent such that base**exponent is closest to num.
    Note that the base**exponent may be either greater or smaller than num.
    In case of a tie, return the smaller value.
    Returns the exponent.

    '''
    exp=1
    while base ** exp < num:
        exp+=1
    return exp if base ** exp - num < num - base ** (exp - 1) else exp - 1
```

Comment: Yeah,i agree I made my method complex for myself. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `elif` is extra. If condition is satisfied, you should return the value.

```
def closest_power2(base, num):
    exp=1
    while base**exp<=num:
        if base**exp <= num <= base**(exp+1):
           num_low = base**exp
           num_high = base**(exp+1)
           return exp if num-num_low<num_high-num else exp+1
        exp += 1
    return 0
```

Emm... In your case, for `exp=8`, the first `if` condition is satisfied. Then you assign `result=exp` (which is 8) and at the next iteration `while` breaks, because `2^9` is not less than `384`, so you return `8`.

Please notice, I've changed `base**exp<num` to `base**exp<=num`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice this.

Comment: Actually `if base**exp <= num <= base**(exp+1):` will always return true because of `while base**exp<=num:` so just writing `if num <= base**(exp+1):` is necessary. Or you can take this part out of while as in my example.

Comment: @alpert Yeah, your while loop is optimal. (If at all use `while` instead of `log`. :) )

Answer (score 0):

this works.

```
def closest_power(base, num):
    bevaluate = True
    exponent = 0
    vale = 0 
    older = 0
    olders = 0
    while bevaluate:
        vale = base ** exponent
        if vale < num:
            older = num - vale
            exponent+=1
        else:
            olders = vale - num
            if older == olders :
                if num == 1:
                    exponent = 0
                else:
                    exponent-=1
                break
            elif older < olders:
                exponent-=1
                break            
            bevaluate = False

    return  exponent
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest grader, the previous answers don't work. You'd come up with something that uses a sensibility term (e.g epsilon). So the criteria to find the proper exponential could be, in this case, the inequality within the absolute difference of the actual estimate and the next one.

```
def closest_power(base, num):
    '''
    base: base of the exponential, integer > 1
    num: number you want to be closest to, integer > 0
    Find the integer exponent such that base**exponent is closest to num.
    Note that the base**exponent may be either greater or smaller than num.
    In case of a tie, return the smaller value.
    Returns the exponent.
    '''
    # Your code here
    n = num 
    while abs((base**n)-num)>=abs((base**(n-1))-num):
        n -= 1
    return int(n)
```